# Why does overflow hidden affect height and how can I fix it in this example?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa51kdh7/

Code:

HTML:
    
        Hello world

```
<span class="span2">
    Goodbye cruel world
</span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

.span1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.span2 {
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 130px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here I am trying to create two spans next to each other, only one of them has overflow: hidden and the other shouldn't have overflow: hidden. For some reason the overflow: hidden affects the heights and they don't line up - even when I use an explicit height.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can also be fixed by adding `vertical-align: top` to the `span`'s CSS rule. The reason that both rules fix the problem is that they enforce the vertical alignment of the divs.

Adding a `vertical-align` rule will keep you from potentially having the elements that follow from needing to be cleared.

Comment: How does this answer why it affects height in the first place? I don't get it. What are you referring to with _both rules_?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just updated your `span` to `float: left` and it works. It's not the `overflow` but the fact the `span`s aren't floated that they are misaligned.

Comment: Thanks it works, but in my case I don't need these elements floated. I'm going with the vertical-align fix instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```